# Angular / Firestore - Get single document and use in view template

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get a single document from a firestore collection that I can reference in the component's view template (like {{invoice.id}}.

I can get the document data as an Observable, but can't get get the values to show when I try to reference this in the template.

**view-invoice.component.html:**

```
<h4 class="page-title">Invoice Summary</h4>

<h5>Invoice ID: {{ (invoice.id | async).id }}</h5>
```

**view-invoice.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

import { Invoice } from '../invoiceModel';import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-invoice',
  templateUrl: './view-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-invoice.component.scss']
})

export class ViewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {

  userId: string;

  invoiceId: any;

  invoicesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Invoice>;
  invoices: Observable<Invoice[]>;

  invoice: Observable<{}>;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private db: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.userId = this.authService.user.uid;

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.invoiceId = params.id;
    })

    this.invoicesCollection = this.db.collection('/invoices');

    this.invoices = this.invoicesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Invoice;
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
        })
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getInvoice();
    console.log('this.invoice: ');
    console.log(this.invoice);
  }

  getInvoice() {
    this.invoice = this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices', ref => ref.where('invoiceId', '==', this.invoiceId).limit(1)).valueChanges().flatMap(result => result);
  }

}
```

Comment: Check this code `{{ invoice | async | json }}` printing result?

Comment: Just tried that and it's printing 'null'

Comment: then you are not getting value to `this.invoice`. check you are getting `this.userId` and `this.invoiceId` before running the query inside `getInvoice()`

Comment: If I remove the async it prints it though. I'm not sure what you mean by getting userId and invoiceId before running the query. Their values are set in the constructor and they're obviously set before the query, otherwise the query wouldn't be working and I wouldn't be able to use the json pipe without async to render the full object